# jQuery Заменить звездочки на выделение жирным?

Tags: css, jquery

Имеется база данных, в некоторых полях которой жирное выделение задается двойными звездами:

```
Какой-то текст **жирный текст** и еще **жирнее текст**.
```

Нужно, чтобы при выводе на сайте оно превращалось в:

```
Какой-то текст <b>жирный текст</b> и еще <b>жирнее текст</b>.
```

Подозреваю, что задача тривиальная и решенная уже 100500 раз, но мне не приходилось раньше особо активно работать с jQuery, поэтому даже не знаю, как такое нагуглить... Ближайшее, что попалось - это использовать .wrap(), но непонятно, как подсунуть ему именно окруженный звездочками текст. Особенно если таких случаев может быть несколько за строку, но надо избежать косяков порядка: `<b> и еще </b>` в примере выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/` — называется [регулярное выражение](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), используется для поиска / замены в строках.

У `*` есть специальное значение, `x*`: Совпадение символа `x` от 0 до много раз подряд. Поэтому звездочки нужно экранировать `\*`, чтобы искать совпадения именно с символом «*».

`(.*?)`: `.` Что угодно, 0 или много раз подряд `*`.

`?` «lazy quantifier», заставляет остановиться при встрече `\*\*`, иначе сожрет все символы от первой пары `**` до последней (игнорируя промежуточные пары).

В строке для замены, `$1` — ссылка на то, что совпало внутри скобок.

Флажок `g` — global, чтобы искал все совпадения в строке, а не останавливался после первого совпадения.

```js
let str = "Какой-то текст **жирный текст** и еще **жирнее текст**.";

document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = bold_wrap(str);

function bold_wrap(str) {
  return str.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: О, замечательно, спасибо большое!

Comment: на тексте `**qwe * asd**` не сработает ведь?

Comment: вместо `[^*]*` проще `.*?` и с учетом вышенаписанного

Comment: @teran Упс, да, спасибо) Был соблазн сделать регулярку из сплошных звездочек)